# What is a substitute for celery root in a soup?

Tags: substitutions, soup, celery

I don't have access to [celery root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celeriac) (celeriac). What can I use instead? Are there any suitable alternatives?

Comment: @hobodave: Should this be edited to say *celeriac* as well?  In the UK I do not know it as *celery root* at all, and people might search for *celeriac*, as it a reasonably common ingredient.

Comment: Added celeriac as a tag. (Is there a way of making these tags equivalent?)

Comment: I'd be interested to know in what application. If it's a casserole, a salad, coleslaw...

Comment: Gary is on the mark.  The answer may depend on how prominent an ingredient the celery root is.

Answer (score 4):

From [Cook's Thesaurus](http://www.foodsubs.com/Roots.html#celeriac)

> turnips OR celery ribs (weaker flavor)
>   OR parsley root OR (in salads of
>   grated vegetables) carrots + dash
>   celery seeds.

Enjoy!

Comment: This answer is just copied verbatim from the [Cook's Thesaurus](http://www.foodsubs.com/Roots.html#celeriac) - the first Google result - without attribution.

Comment: And is that wrong?

Comment: there are two major issues, one is copyright (we can't just plagiarize work, and call it our own), and the second is precedent. [Here is a meta link explaining plagiarism in questions](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/757/15), the same applies for answers that do not attribute sources and try to pass off another's work as one's own. Beyond that, it is unethical to some, myself included, because it can be seen as lying and showing disrespect toward someone else.

Comment: I accept this and will work different from now!

Comment: Edited to show suitable attribution

Answer (score 0):

For a soup, you could probably use parsnips, rutabega (aka swedes), or even potatoes in place of celery root.  Carrots would probably be fine too, but if you're puréeing the soup, they'll probably affect the color.

If you would like to find celery root, you might try an asian market.  In the past, I've had success at a chinese market  when all of the other local stores were out of celery root (in San Francisco).